# API getting timeout error with JMETER and python and working in POSTMAN

Tags: python, python-requests, jmeter, postman, connection-timeout

I have a POST request that is getting success in POSTMAN, but the same request is throwing timeout exception in JMETER and python-requests, please help me to understand what might be wrong.

java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Comment: Please add more information to your post, like your JMeter script configuration and python code.

Answer (score -1):

Most probably your server cannot respond fast enough and JMeter terminates the connection without waiting for the response.

[Postman default configuration](https://learning.postman.com/docs/getting-started/settings/) is to wait "forever"

[image]

JMeter's [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler behaviour should be the same

[image]

however there could be some default timeouts on JVM or OS level which have an impact so it makes sense to explicitly increase the timeout at the "Advanced" tab of the HTTP Request sampler (or if you have more than one HTTP Request sampler - go for [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults), this way you will be able to set the timeout for all HTTP Request samplers at once)

Also check that you're sending the same request (protocol, host, port, path, etc.) and pay extra attention to [HTTP Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers), in JMeter you need to configure request headers via [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager)

And finally I can think of the situation where you need a proxy in order to be able to connect to the system under test, i.e. Postman is using the proxy and in JMeter you need to [set it](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server)